# Can't send descriptor to remote device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I developed an BLE application on Android called A to work with my device deviceA.
It is working very well. Now I am stuck in the following case:
I start other BLE application called B and connect with its device called deviceB.
It is in foreground.
My application is running in background.
I start to connect deviceA to application A.
It runs to write descriptor to deviceA and receive onWriteDescriptor with status GATT_SUCCESS. However deviceA can't receive descriptor data.
In the log file, I see that application B start BLE scan/ stop BLE scan many times.
Are there any experts can explain me why deviceA can't receive data in this case?
Thanks you very much.

Comment: You mean that on the air there are no ATT Write Request and ATT Write Response packets corresponding to your descriptor write?

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, Emil. I am newbie of BLE. How I can capture these packets? I just understand it in context of Android programming.

Comment: I read my question again and understand what you mean. I am sorry for make you confused. I explain more:In my application, I am waiting for onCharacteristicChanged call back from GATT after onDescriptorWrite callback. So I guessed that device side can't receive the descriptor value so it didn't response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also call setCharacteristicNotification which tells Android to forward the notifications to your app when Android receives the notification.

Comment: In my question, I said that my application works well when it run alone (not start application B). So setCharacteristicNotification must be called.